# perl : split a string using a newline character

Tags: perl, split

I want to split the words of a string with a newline character.

I have tried :

```
 $string = 'One Two Three';
 my @array3 = split("\n",$string);
```

I want the output like :

```
One
Two 
Three
```

Can this be possible without using for loop?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to use the [`split`](http://p3rl.org/split) function, splitting the `$string` on regions of space (`" "` is special cased). Then take the generated list and [`join`](http://p3rl.org/join) it with the newline character `"\n"`.

```
my $string = 'One Two Three';
my $output = join "\n", split " ", $string;
```

(view execution at http://ideone.com/Sd0Wp)

In your code you split the string on newlines. Naturally, this returns only one value because there are no newline characters.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need use split-join for this task.
Just use regex to replace all spaces to newlines.

```
$string = 'One Two Three';
$string =~ s/\s/\n/g;
print $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$string = 'One Two Three';
my @array3 = split (' ', $string);

print join ("\n", @array3);
```

This will split the strings on spaces and join them with newlines when you print them.

Answer (score 1):

Your string doesnt contain newline characters. Possibly you need split it with space characters. So try this code:

```
$string = 'One Two Three';
my @array3 = split(/\s+/,$string);
```

Comment: He wanted a new line after splitting though

Comment: Anyway he wanted to split string firstly to have a list of words.